# Recovering a page from the drafts

Tags: pages

I recently deleted a page mistakenly. When i tried to recover it, it went into the drafts. I want it to come back into the published pages but i have failed after several attempts. What do i do? thanks

Comment: did u check the trash?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily recover a page from the drafts.
follow the steps below:

1. See a link " Trash" on the top of pages listing section.
2. Click on that link which will take you to the section where all the trashed pages are listed.
3. Select the page(which you want to publish) using the checkboxes against them.
4. Select Restore from Bulk Actions dropdown, then hit the Apply button.

Now go to pages listing section and you should see the page published again.